# Problema al usar hover y margenes en divs

Tags: html, css

estoy refrescando un poco de CSS y por algún motivo tengo un par de problemas.

Quiero hacer dos cosas que no me salen... La primera es que al pasar el ratón por encima de los links Menú 1 / 2 / 3, quiero que se ilumine tanto el texto como el icono a la misma vez, lo maximo que he conseguido es que se iluminen pero de manera separada, y quiero que lo haga pero en el mismo conjunto (el icono, el cual no aparece en el codigo que pondre abajo se ilumina en rojo), también quiero que al pasar el ratón por encima se ilumine el fondo pero con la altura especifica del div que esta detras, es decir que el hover ocupe todo el alto del div de atrás... he probado con paddings y queda "Bien" pero no del todo...

Otra cosa que quiero es pegar el div "menu" a los margenes laterales derecho e izquierdo, lo he conseguido con margin negativo pero me salen dos problemas, el primero es que el siguiente div que use debajo del div menu se me queda a la derecha "atascado" encima del otro.... en vez de quedarse justamente debajo y en la derecha y el otro problema es que al pegar el div a los margenes con margin negativo aparece un scroll horizontal que no me gusta nada.

Alguna ayuda? Muchas gracias... dejo el código abajo:

```css
header {
    text-align: center;
    color: #8a2be2;
    font-family: monospace;
}
#menu {
    background-color: #98e624;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px 0px 1px 0px;
    border-color: #034203;
    margin: -8px;
}
#content {
    background-color: #478bca;
}
.medic {
    color:#478bca;
    padding-right: 5px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}
.medic:hover {
    color:red;
}
ul {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    text-align: center;
}

li{
    display: inline;
    padding: 1.2em 0.5em 1em 0.5em;
    font-weight: bold;
}

li:hover{
    color:red;
    background-color: khaki;
}

a {
    color: #045e04;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#content {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}
```

```html
<!doctype HTML>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css"> <!--El: type="text/css" no es necesario incluirlo-->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/all.css"> <!-- Este enlace es el de los iconos que te hablé de la web de Font Awesome-->

</head>
<title> Test 1 </title>
<body>
    <!--<main> // No es necesario-->
<!-- YA existe una etiqueta "Header" en HTML5, esto no lo necesitas <div id="header">-->
    <header>
    <h1> TEST 1 </h1>
    </header>
    <!--</div>--> 
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a link href="#"><i class="fas fa-user-md medic"></i>Menú 1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a link href="#"><i class="fas fa-user-md medic"></i>Menú 2</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a link href="#"><i class="fas fa-user-md medic"></i>Menú 3</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="content">
    Contenido
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: es decir quieres añadirle como una especie de neon a la letra cuando pase no?

Comment: espero haberte ayudado

Answer (score 0):

```css
header {
    text-align: center;
    color: #8a2be2;
    font-family: monospace;
}
#menu {
    background-color: #98e624;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px 0px 1px 0px;
    border-color: #034203;
    margin: -8px;
}
#content {
    background-color: #478bca;
}
.medic {
    color:#478bca;
    padding-right: 5px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}
.medic:hover {
    color:red;
}
ul {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    text-align: center;
}

li{
    display: inline;
    padding: 1.2em 0.5em 1em 0.5em;
    font-weight: bold;
}

li:hover{
    color:red;
text-shadow:1px 2px 3px #FFF, 4px 5px 6px #112,
                    7px 8px 9px #223;
    background-color: khaki;
}

a {
    
    text-decoration: none;
}
#content {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}
```

```html
<!doctype HTML>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css"> <!--El: type="text/css" no es necesario incluirlo-->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/all.css"> <!-- Este enlace es el de los iconos que te hablé de la web de Font Awesome-->

</head>
<title> Test 1 </title>
<body>
    <!--<main> // No es necesario-->
<!-- YA existe una etiqueta "Header" en HTML5, esto no lo necesitas <div id="header">-->
    <header>
    <h1> TEST 1 </h1>
    </header>
    <!--</div>--> 
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a link href="#"><i class="fas fa-user-md medic"></i>Menú 1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a link href="#"><i class="fas fa-user-md medic"></i>Menú 2</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a link href="#"><i class="fas fa-user-md medic"></i>Menú 3</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="content">
    Contenido
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Yo le solucionado con esto : `text-shadow:1px 2px 3px #FFF, 4px 5px 6px #112, 7px 8px 9px #223;` esto lo que hace es añadir un efecto de sombra 3d. La parte del px es el tamaño de la letra y lo siguiente el color en hexadecimal

Answer (score 0):

Oh vale, disculpa

@gbianchi @Javier G. Raya

En principio era eso, ahora mismo no consigo quitarle los margenes laterales al div "menu" y pegarlo al ancho de la pagina si no es usando el siguiente codigo:

- { margin:0px; padding:0px; }

Si en vez de usar eso uso una clase y la añado al div, no funciona..

```css
* {
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    }
header {
    text-align: center;
    color: #8a2be2;
    font-family: monospace;
}
#menu {
    background-color: #98e624;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px 0px 1px 0px;
    border-color: #034203;
    width: 100;
}
.medic {
    color:#478bca;
    padding-right: 5px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}
.medic:hover {
    color:red;
}
ul {
    margin: 0px;
    text-align: center; margin:0px;
}

li{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 1.2em 0.5em 1em 0.5em;
    font-weight: bold;
}

li:hover{
    color:red;
    background-color: khaki;
}
li:hover a, li:hover a i{
    color:red;
}

a {
    color: #045e04;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#content {
    background-color: #2fa52f;
    width: 99.5%;
    margin-left: 0.5%;
}
```

```html
<!doctype HTML>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css"> <!--El: type="text/css" no es necesario incluirlo-->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/all.css"> <!-- Este enlace es el de los iconos que te hablé de la web de Font Awesome-->

</head>
<title> Test 1 </title>
<body>
    <!--<main> // No es necesario-->
<!-- YA existe una etiqueta "Header" en HTML5, esto no lo necesitas <div id="header">-->
    <header>
    <h1> TEST 1 </h1>
    </header>
    <!--</div>--> 
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a link href="#"><i class="fas fa-user-md medic"></i>Menú 1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a link href="#"><i class="fas fa-user-md medic"></i>Menú 2</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a link href="#"><i class="fas fa-user-md medic"></i>Menú 3</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="content">
    Contenido
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Esto es una respuesta o parte de tu pregunta?

Comment: Perdon, es parte de la pregunta...

Comment: Por favor todo esto junto con la otra *respuesta* debe ir en tu pregunta, quitalas de la zona de respuestas, edita tu pregunta y agregalo ahi